# Incorrect classification of multiple listings entries

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

My problem is as follows:
I have 3 different listings environments namely List of Matlab Outputs, List of Matlab Code and List of Pseudocodes. However all listings are under List of Matlab Outputs while the List of Codes and Pseudocodes are empty which is not supposed to be the case. I want all Matlab outputs (e.g Matlab Output 1.1,...) to be under List of Matlab Outputs, all Matlab codes (e.g Matlab Code 1.1,...) to be under List of Matlab Codes and all Pseudocodes (e.g Pseudocode 1.1,...) to be under List of Pseudocodes as shown in the picture below:  [image: The output I am desiring in the presence of ALL the packages I have loaded]
I am looking for a solution that solves the problem in presence of all the packages I loaded. I suspect there are some lines of code that are causing this problem considering the fact that if some lines of code are deleted, I get the desired output. I have attached a picture showing the problem I am facing. I am writing a book so please I want the loaded packages not to be deleted when providing the solution. Below is the picture showing the problem and my MWE respectively:
[image: The problem I am facing]

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany,twoside]{book}
\raggedbottom
\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm,a4paper] 
{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{I}{!{\vrule width 1pt}}
\newlength\savedwidth
\newcommand\whline{\noalign{\global\savedwidth\arrayrulewidth
\global\arrayrulewidth 1pt}%
\hline
\noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth\savedwidth}}
\usepackage{xcolor, graphicx}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hhline}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[noindentafter,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\definecolor{mintbg}{rgb}{.63,.79,.95}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\newcommand*\myheaderfooterfont{\normalfont}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[ragged]{sidecap}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont}
%\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}
\setlength\cftbeforetoctitleskip{-2cm}
\setlength\cftbeforeloftitleskip{-2cm}
\setlength\cftbeforelottitleskip{-2cm}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\normalfont}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[numbered, framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\let\ph\mlplaceholder % shorter macro
\lstMakeShortInline"

\makeatletter
% --------------------------------------- C++
\newcommand{\lstlistmatlaboutputname}{List of Matlab Output}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofmatlaboutput{\bgroup
\let\contentsname\lstlistmatlaboutputname
\let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{loc}}%
\tableofcontents \egroup}
\lstnewenvironment{matlaboutput}[1][]{%
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Matlab Output}%
\xpatchcmd*{\lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{loc}{}{}%
\lstset{language=C++,#1}}
{}
% --------------------------------------- R
\newcommand{\lstlistmatlabcodename}{List of Matlab Code}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofmatlabcode{\bgroup
\let\contentsname\lstlistmatlabcodename
\let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lor}}%
\tableofcontents \egroup}
\lstnewenvironment{matlabcode}[1][]{%
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Matlab Code}%
\xpatchcmd*{\lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{lor}{}{}%
\lstset{language=R,#1}}
{}
% --------------------------------------- Pseudocode
\newcommand{\lstlistpseudocodename}{List of Pseudocode}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofpseudocode{\bgroup
\let\contentsname\lstlistpseudocodename
\let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lop}}%
\tableofcontents \egroup}
\lstnewenvironment{pseudocode}[1][]{%
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Pseudocode}%
\xpatchcmd*{\lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{lop}{}{}%
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,#1}}
{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\lstlistofmatlaboutput}{\begingroup
\tocfile{\lstlistmatlaboutputname}{lol}
\endgroup}
\renewcommand{\lstlistofmatlabcode}{\begingroup
\tocfile{\lstlistmatlabcodename}{lol}
\endgroup}
\renewcommand{\lstlistofpseudocode}{\begingroup
\tocfile{\lstlistpseudocodename}{lol}
\endgroup}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{-4\p@}}} 
{}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip-4pt}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{person.m}
classdef person
properties %(here, properties is a keyword)
mass=80;
height=1.80;
end
methods
function BMI = getBMI(height,weight)
BMI = person.mass/person.mass^2;
end
end
end
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{sample.m}
%% Code sections are highlighted.
% System command are supported...
!gzip sample.m
% ... as is line continuation.
A = [1, 2, 3,... % (mimicking the ouput is good)
4, 5, 6]
fid = fopen('testFile.text', 'w')
for i=1:10
fprintf(fid,'%6.2f \n', i);
end
x=1; %% this is just a comment, though
% Context-sensitive keywords get highlighted correctly...
p = properties(mydate); %(here, properties is a function)
x = linspace(0,1,101);
y = x(end:-1:1)
% ... even in nonsensical code.
]end()()(((end end)end ))))end (function end
%{
    block comments are supported
    %} even
runaway block comments
are
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document} 

\lstlistofmatlaboutput
\lstlistofmatlabcode    
\lstlistofpseudocode

\chapter{Listings}
\begin{matlaboutput}[caption = {Some class definition}]
classdef person
properties %(here, properties is a keyword)
mass=80;
height=1.80;
end
methods
function BMI = getBMI(height,weight)
BMI = person.mass/person.mass^2;
end
end
end
\end{matlaboutput}

\begin{matlabcode}[caption = {For educational purposes}]
% example of while loop using placeholders
while "\ph{condition}"
if "\ph{something-bad-happens}"
break
else
% do something useful
end
% do more things
end
\end{matlabcode}

\begin{matlabcode}[caption = {Sample code from Matlab}]
%% Code sections are highlighted.
% System command are supported...
!gzip sample.m
% ... as is line continuation.
A = [1, 2, 3,... % (mimicking the ouput is good)
4, 5, 6]
fid = fopen('testFile.text', 'w')
for i=1:10
fprintf(fid,'%6.2f \n', i);
end
x=1; %% this is just a comment, though
% Context-sensitive keywords get highlighted correctly...
p = properties(mydate); %(here, properties is a function)
x = linspace(0,1,101);
y = x(end:-1:1)
% ... even in nonsensical code.
]end()()(((end end)end ))))end (function end
%{
block comments are supported
%} even
runaway block comments
are
\end{matlabcode}
\begin{pseudocode}[caption={Hello world}]
print "Hello world"
\end{pseudocode}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please format your code.  It also looks like you're including many packages.  Are they all needed for a Minimal Working Example?

Comment: You've still not formatted everything.  And you're including a few paragraphs that have more to do with an autobiography than listings.  Can't you delete everything unrelated to the three listings in question?

Comment: @Teepeemm, I have formatted the code. All the packages in my code are needed. I have deleted the chapters unrelated to the three listings in question.

Comment: @itc I just wrote an answer in chat. Seems you logged out while I was still typing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I delete all unrelated packages, OP should take a look how to provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). Following is a working example:

> Edit: This is working with latest `caption` package (2022-03-29), earlier version please use commented lines instead.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}


% --------------------------------------- C++
\newcommand{\lstlistmatlaboutputname}{List of Matlab Output}
\newcommand{\lstlistofmatlaboutput}{\begingroup
\tocfile{\lstlistmatlaboutputname}{loc}
\endgroup}
% --------------------------------------- R
\newcommand{\lstlistmatlabcodename}{List of Matlab Code}
\newcommand{\lstlistofmatlabcode}{\begingroup
\tocfile{\lstlistmatlabcodename}{lor}
\endgroup}
% --------------------------------------- Pseudocode
\newcommand{\lstlistpseudocodename}{List of Pseudocode}
\newcommand{\lstlistofpseudocode}{\begingroup
\tocfile{\lstlistpseudocodename}{lop}
\endgroup}

\makeatletter
\lstnewenvironment{matlaboutput}[1][]{%
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Matlab Output}%
\renewcommand{\ext@lstlisting}{loc}%
%\xpatchcmd*{\caption@ORI@lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{loc}{}{}% use this with earlier version caption package
\lstset{language=C++,#1}}%
{}

\lstnewenvironment{matlabcode}[1][]{%
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Matlab Code}%
\renewcommand{\ext@lstlisting}{lor}%
%\xpatchcmd*{\caption@ORI@lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{lor}{}{}% use this with earlier version caption package
\lstset{language=R,#1}}
{}

\lstnewenvironment{pseudocode}[1][]{%
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Pseudocode}%
\renewcommand{\ext@lstlisting}{lop}%
%\xpatchcmd*{\caption@ORI@lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{lop}{}{}% use this with earlier version caption package
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,#1}}%
{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lstlistofmatlaboutput
\lstlistofmatlabcode    
\lstlistofpseudocode

\chapter{Listings}
\begin{matlaboutput}[caption = {Some class definition}]
% example matlab output
\end{matlaboutput}

\begin{matlabcode}[caption = {For educational purposes}]
% example matlab code 1
\end{matlabcode}

\begin{matlabcode}[caption = {Sample code from Matlab}]
% example matlab code 2
\end{matlabcode}

\begin{pseudocode}[caption={Hello world}]
% example pseudocode
\end{pseudocode}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

> Edit: The problem is caused by the new `caption` package setup. Following is the working example with all your packages:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany,twoside]{book}
\raggedbottom
\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm,a4paper] 
{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{I}{!{\vrule width 1pt}}
\newlength\savedwidth
\newcommand\whline{\noalign{\global\savedwidth\arrayrulewidth
        \global\arrayrulewidth 1pt}%
    \hline
    \noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth\savedwidth}}
\usepackage{xcolor, graphicx}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hhline}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[noindentafter,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\definecolor{mintbg}{rgb}{.63,.79,.95}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\newcommand*\myheaderfooterfont{\normalfont}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[ragged]{sidecap}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont}
%\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}
\setlength\cftbeforetoctitleskip{-2cm}
\setlength\cftbeforeloftitleskip{-2cm}
\setlength\cftbeforelottitleskip{-2cm}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\normalfont}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[numbered, framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\let\ph\mlplaceholder % shorter macro
\lstMakeShortInline"

\makeatletter
% --------------------------------------- C++
\newcommand{\lstlistmatlaboutputname}{List of Matlab Output}
\lstnewenvironment{matlaboutput}[1][]{%
    \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Matlab Output}%
    \renewcommand{\ext@lstlisting}{loc}%
    %\xpatchcmd*{\caption@ORI@lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{loc}{}{}% use this with earlier version caption package
    \lstset{language=C++,#1}}
{}
% --------------------------------------- R
\newcommand{\lstlistmatlabcodename}{List of Matlab Code}
\lstnewenvironment{matlabcode}[1][]{%
    \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Matlab Code}%
    \renewcommand{\ext@lstlisting}{lor}%
    %\xpatchcmd*{\caption@ORI@lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{lor}{}{}% use this with earlier version caption package
    \lstset{language=R,#1}}
{}
% --------------------------------------- Pseudocode
\newcommand{\lstlistpseudocodename}{List of Pseudocode}
\lstnewenvironment{pseudocode}[1][]{%
    \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Pseudocode}%
    \renewcommand{\ext@lstlisting}{lop}%
    %\xpatchcmd*{\caption@ORI@lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{lop}{}{}% use this with earlier version caption package
    \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,#1}}
{}

\newcommand{\lstlistofmatlaboutput}{\begingroup
    \tocfile{\lstlistmatlaboutputname}{loc}
    \endgroup}
\newcommand{\lstlistofmatlabcode}{\begingroup
    \tocfile{\lstlistmatlabcodename}{lor}
    \endgroup}
\newcommand{\lstlistofpseudocode}{\begingroup
    \tocfile{\lstlistpseudocodename}{lop}
    \endgroup}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{-4\p@}}} 
{}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip-4pt}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue
}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{person.m}
    classdef person
    properties %(here, properties is a keyword)
    mass=80;
    height=1.80;
    end
    methods
    function BMI = getBMI(height,weight)
    BMI = person.mass/person.mass^2;
    end
    end
    end
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{sample.m}
    %% Code sections are highlighted.
    % System command are supported...
    !gzip sample.m
    % ... as is line continuation.
    A = [1, 2, 3,... % (mimicking the ouput is good)
    4, 5, 6]
    fid = fopen('testFile.text', 'w')
    for i=1:10
    fprintf(fid,'%6.2f \n', i);
    end
    x=1; %% this is just a comment, though
    % Context-sensitive keywords get highlighted correctly...
    p = properties(mydate); %(here, properties is a function)
    x = linspace(0,1,101);
    y = x(end:-1:1)
    % ... even in nonsensical code.
    ]end()()(((end end)end ))))end (function end
    %{
        block comments are supported
        %} even
    runaway block comments
    are
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document} 
    
    \lstlistofmatlaboutput
    \lstlistofmatlabcode    
    \lstlistofpseudocode
    
    \chapter{Listings}
    \begin{matlaboutput}[breaklines,escapeinside=!!,caption = {Some class definition}]
        classdef person
        properties %(here, properties is a keyword)
        mass=80;
        height=1.80;
        end
        methods
        function BMI = getBMI(height,weight)
        BMI = person.mass/person.mass^2;
        end
        end
        end
    \end{matlaboutput}
    
    \begin{matlabcode}[caption = {For educational purposes}]
        % example of while loop using placeholders
        while "\ph{condition}"
        if "\ph{something-bad-happens}"
        break
        else
        % do something useful
        end
        % do more things
        end
    \end{matlabcode}
    
    \begin{matlabcode}[caption = {Sample code from Matlab}]
        %% Code sections are highlighted.
        % System command are supported...
        !gzip sample.m
        % ... as is line continuation.
        A = [1, 2, 3,... % (mimicking the ouput is good)
        4, 5, 6]
        fid = fopen('testFile.text', 'w')
        for i=1:10
        fprintf(fid,'%6.2f \n', i);
        end
        x=1; %% this is just a comment, though
        % Context-sensitive keywords get highlighted correctly...
        p = properties(mydate); %(here, properties is a function)
        x = linspace(0,1,101);
        y = x(end:-1:1)
        % ... even in nonsensical code.
        ]end()()(((end end)end ))))end (function end
        %{
            block comments are supported
            %} even
        runaway block comments
        are
    \end{matlabcode}
    \begin{pseudocode}[caption={Hello world}]
        print "Hello world"
    \end{pseudocode}    
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I am writing a book and I am using all those packages. Is there any package that is causing my problem from the code I provided above? If you delete some packages like you did, everything works. However, can you assist me with a solution that works when all the packages in my MWE are loaded? I want all the packages in my preamble not to be deleted please because I need a solution in the presence of all those packages. Thank you.

Comment: @itc As I said, I delete all unrelated packages associate with the problem. It should work if you have other packages. Have you try the solution yet?

Comment: @itc I tested it with all your packages. It is working for me. And I post the working example with your packages. If this one is still not working for you. Just let me know.  Maybe some packages you didn't include the in the example cause the problem.

Comment: when I run the last code you posted that includes all the packages, the List of Matlab Outputs, Code and Pseudocode pages are all blank. I am using TeXLive 2022 alongside Texstudio.What could be the problem?

Comment: I also checked the LOC, LOR, and LOP files in the folder with my TEX file. Their size is 0Kb.

Comment: the code is still not working. I copied and pasted the last code you posted and I am now getting blank List of Matlab Outputs, Codes and Pseudocodes. I am stuck. I need your assistance please.

Comment: @itc I update the answer. The problem is caused by latest `caption` package. Now it should be working.

Comment: Thank you very much @Tom, the problem has been solved. I wouldn't have done it without your assistance. I didn't know that the updated caption package can have such effects on the listings environments.

Comment: @itc You are welcome!

Comment: Dear @Tom, I have a question that I am kindly requesting for a solution at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/656728/classifying-matlab-code-and-pseudocodes-under-list-of-codes-and-matlab-and-r-out?noredirect=1#comment1636761_656728. I would greatly appreciate if you can offer some assistance.